# Send Email To Form User With Document Links

Tags: php, forms

I've got a very generic form.   I want the user input their email address, select any documents they wish to recieve, and want an email to generate back to them with the download links to the documents they selected.  I have done this in the past, but my mind has gone blank.  Any help you can provide is appreciated!  Thanks.

Here's ths form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="autoreply.php">
  <label class="description" for="email">Your Email Address</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
  <br />
  Document 1:
  <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="document1" />
  <br />
  Document 2:
  <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="document2" />
  <br />
  Document 3:
  <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="document3" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST['send'] == 1)){ 

    $documents = array( 
                    'document1' => 'http://www.example.com/document1.doc', 
                    'document2' => 'http://www.example.com/document2.doc', 
                    'document3' => 'http://www.example.com/document3.doc' 
                ); 

    $to      = '$email'; 
    $subject = 'the subject'; 
    $message = "hello\n\n"; 

    if(isset($_POST['document']) && count($_POST['document']) > 0){ 
        foreach($_POST['document'] as $doc){ 
            if(isset($documents[$doc])){ 
                $message .= "Here is ".$documents[$doc]."\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 


    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a attachment, to include to the document, or if the documents are plain text, include them in your message.

When you want to include a attachment, most convenient is to use a ready made mailer class, like [swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

If you want to include the documents in yout message you should use something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['document']) && count($_POST['document']) > 0){ 
        foreach($_POST['document'] as $doc){ 
            if(isset($documents[$doc])){ 
                $message .= "Here is ".$documents[$doc]."\n\n";
                $message .= file_get_contents( filename_of($documents[$doc]) ); 
            } 
        } 
}
```

of course, you have to write a function for getting the filename from the document name.